# Error: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set root cause java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set

Tags: mysql, jsp

```
<%Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql","root","12345");  
                   String username = (String)session.getAttribute("username"); 
                   
                   Statement stmt = con.createStatement(); 
                   String query3 ="select * from empinfo where EUsername='"+username+"'";
                    ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(query3);                 
                  while(rs1.next()) {
                  String department= rs1.getString("EDepartment");
                 String u = "select * from empinfo where EDepartment='"+department+"'";
                   ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(u);              
                  while(rs.next()) {          %>
                <option><%=rs.getString("EUsername")%></option>
                <%}
%>
                </select></p><%}%>
```

Having this
"

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set

root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set"

error.

Comment: Which SQL code caused the exception?This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: Don't know which SQL code caused. It did not specify it. exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set

root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set

This is all it shows in error.

Comment: Did you find something wrong in or about the code?

Comment: I want to have all username from empinfo table who have same department as the session username. How can have those username ?     @RomanC

Comment: It's not enough information for the answer. I suggest you debug your code to diagnose the problem. As far as it's written impossible to provide you a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%                 
               Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
               Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql","root","12345");  
               String username = (String)session.getAttribute("username"); 
               
               Statement stmt = con.createStatement(); 
               String query3 ="select * from empinfo where EUsername='"+username+"'";
               ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(query3);                 
               while(rs1.next()) {
               Statement stm = con.createStatement(); 
               String department= rs1.getString("EDepartment");
               String u = "select * from empinfo where EDepartment='"+department+"'";
               ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(u);              
               while(rs.next()) {          %>
               <option><%=rs.getString("EUsername")%></option>
            <%
            }}%>
```

I solved the error. It was coming because I didn't create different create statement objects for the other queries.